# Weird behavior with NavigationSplitView and @State

Tags: swiftui

I have a NavigationSplitView in my app, I have an @State variable in my detail view that gets created in init.

When I select something from the sidebar and the detail view renders, at first everything looks ok. But when I select a different item on the sidebar, the contents of the @state variable don't get recreated.

Using the debugger I can see the init of the detail view get called every time I select a new item in the sidebar, and I can see the @State variable get created. But when it actually renders, the @State variable still contains the previous selection's values.

I've reduced this problem to a test case I'll paste below. The top text in the detail view is a variable passed in from the sidebar, and the second line of text is generated by the @State variable. Expected behavior would be, if I select "one" the detail view would display "one" and "The name is one". If I select "two" the detail view would display "two" and "The name is two".

Instead, if I select "one" first, it displays correctly. But when I select "two", it displays "two" and "The name is one".

Note that if I select "two" as the first thing I do after launching the app, it correctly displays "two" and "The name is two", but when I click on "one" next, it will display "one" and "the name is two". So the state variable is being set once, then never changing again,

Here's the sample code and screenshots:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedItem: Item.ID? = nil
    
    private let items = [Item(name: "one"), Item(name: "two"), Item(name: "three")]
    
    func itemForID(_ id: UUID?) -> Item? {
        guard let itemID = id else { return nil }
        return items.first(where: { item in
            item.id == itemID
        })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView{
            List(selection: $selectedItem) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.name)
                        .tag(item.id)
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            if let name = itemForID(selectedItem)?.name {
                DetailView(name: name)
            } else {
                Text("Select an item")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    
    @State var detailItem: DetailItem
    
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        _detailItem = State(wrappedValue: DetailItem(name: name))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
            Text(detailItem.computedText)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailItem {
    let name: String
    
    var computedText: String {
        return "The name is \(name)"
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: First selection, expected result]
[image: Second selection, expected to see "The name is two"]

Comment: Oddly, the State variable _does_ seem to get set in the `init`; if you add `print(detailItem.computedText)` after the assignment it prints the correct value

Comment: This isn't related to the `NavigationSplitView`. If you put the List and Detail in an `HStack` you get the same result

Comment: Weird! Yeah, when I set breakpoints, I could see init getting called, and the state variable being set... then it seems to just get ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with NavigationSplitView, but how you initialise @State property.

According to the Apple document on @State (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state):

> Don’t initialise a state property of a view at the point in the view hierarchy where you instantiate the view, because this can conflict with the storage management that SwiftUI provides.

As well as the documentation of init(wrappedValue:) (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/wrappedvalue):

> Don’t call this initializer directly. Instead, declare a property with the State attribute, and provide an initial value:

```
@State private var isPlaying: Bool = false
```

From my understanding, if you force to initialise the state in the view init, it will persist through the lifetime of the view, and subsequence change of it won't take any effect on the view.

The recommended way in Apple documentation is to create the struct in the parent view and pass it to the child view, and if you need to change the struct in the child view, use @Binding to allow read and write access.

If you want to ignore the documentation and force it to work, you can give an id to your DetailView, forcing it to refresh the view when the item id has changed:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView{
        List(selection: $selectedItem) {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                    .tag(item.id)
            }
        }
    } detail: {
        if let name = itemForID(selectedItem)?.name {
            DetailView(name: name).id(selectedItem)
        } else {
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I saw that in the documentation, but it was actually the next sentence that put me down this wrong path: "place [the state variable] in the highest view in the view hierarchy that needs access to the value.". In my application, the parent view doesn't need access to the value, but the detail view does. So I was trying to instantiate it in the detail view. But, since I need to know an ID passed in from the parent, I had to instantiate in init. 

Thanks, this looks like the right answer! And in fact, I had worked around this by making it a binding already,

Comment: I think the first quote is talking about don't do `MyView(thing: State(wrappedValue: value))` rather than inside init but agree it should be avoided regardless.

Comment: What I noticed is if the state is initialised in the view init, the swiftui view won't be updated. It will only notice any changes of state in the body. There are quite a number of discussion and articles about this. Ex: https://sarunw.com/posts/state-variable-initialization/

Answer (score 2):

Question. What is the purpose of having detailItem as a @State? if you remove the @State, this test case works.

Will the way computedText change over time?

```
struct DetailView: View {
    
//    @State var detailItem: DetailItem
    var detailItem: DetailItem
    
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
//        _detailItem = State(wrappedValue: DetailItem(name: name))
        detailItem = DetailItem(name: name)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
            Text(detailItem.computedText)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course this is a simplified test case. In the actual application, I was trying to follow this guideline from Apple: "...always declare state as private, and place it in the highest view in the view hierarchy that needs access to the value." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

In my case, the parent gets an ID of a selected struct, but doesn't need to load the struct. So following that principle above, the @state should be in the detail view, generated from the ID passed into it from the parent

Comment: I've worked around this for now by making the detailItem a Binding in the detail view, and creating the state in the parent. But now I'm not following Apple's guideline for state.

Comment: Oh, and it needs to be @state because the detail view (in the real application) is editing the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your Item struct is bad, if the name is unique it should be:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: String { name }
    let name: String
}
```

Otherwise:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}
```

Comment: Good point. I edited my post above to fix this. However this bug (if that's what it is) is still there, the behavior I described is identical.